# Alexandrov polyhedron editor

Tags: data-visualization, 3d, visual-design

I would like to find out how a polyhedron would look like in 3D (ie visualise it) if I know it's development (ie its intrinsic metric). I heard that one such software is the: Alexandrov Polyhedron Editor. Where can I find it? If it is not free,  are there any similar free software doing the same job? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking where to find a specific piece of software is off-topic.  Asking for similar software is fine, given your reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software you mention is listed on this page: https://alexandrov-polyhedron-editor.winsite.com/. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks,  but it is not open to public.

Comment: @dmtri: When you visit that address do you get a page that offers a 'Download now' button? I just used that and got a jnlp file.

Comment: Yes, but it redirects always to TU-BERLIN.....